# getting output of json link using ui-route angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to display a json result.I have these code using ngRoute.

```
    .controller('ChannelViewCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $scope.channel = {};
        $http.get('http://example.com/channel/' +  $routeParams.id).success(function(result){
            $scope.channel = result[0];

        });
```

I'm trying now to use ui-route with almost the same code, I only edit `$routeParams.id` to `$stateParams.id`

```
routerApp.controller('ChannelViewCtrl', function ($scope,$stateParams,$http) {

        $http.get('http://example.com/channel/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(result){
            $scope.channel = result[0];
        })
    });
```

However I got this error:

> No input file specified.

Anybody got an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to reach a `.php` file?

Comment: @Goldenowner. thanks for reaching out. If you are asking about the link, it's from a drupal views generated json.

Comment: seems like I'll be just going to ngRoute path